# How to disable bottle by default?

Tags: linux, homebrew

I used to have something like the below in a formula to disable bottle

`bottle :disable, "Reason to ignore bottle"`

This `bottle :disable` option was removed recently.
Logs from Homebrew 3.3.9 says there is no replacement. Why?

```
Error: automake: Calling bottle :disable is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core)
```

I know I can use `--build-from-source`, but I want to make that default.

Comment: You could check this question on [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429492/warning-calling-bottle-unneeded-is-deprecated-there-is-no-replacement) if it is helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: My question is more like how to write a formula that has bottles being disabled by default.